# Android sound recorder with gps location

Tags: android, audio, gps

I'm looking for an Android voice/sound recorder that saves the GPS location where the voice note was made.

I know there are some GPS tracking apps that can do something like that, but it's too slow for what I need (you need to save the tracking point, then manually attach a recording to it. Too many steps for a quick voice note on the field). I just need to record a sound, and automatically attach the GPS location.

Comment: Not tried, but sounds like [GeoArchive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexul.GeoArchive.app) could match that. If it does, feel free to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (I can't do that anyway, not knowing the app myself).

Comment: Can't register (maybe it's down), but from the website it looks like the notes can only include text and images, not sound. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Was worth a try. Sorry it didn't fit; I've checked [my app lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists), and that was the only one that sounded promising…